# Замена символов в строке по номеру

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Есть строка `a='IIIIIIIII'`, есть список `b=[1,2,3,4,5]`. Необходимо заменить `'I'` на `'.'`. В списке в цифры это как номера (не индексы) строковых символов.

```
for i,x in enumerate(s):
    if i+1==b:
       s.replace('I','.')
    print(i,x)
print(s)
```

Comment: Не могли бы вы более понятно объяснить...

Comment: в условии дана строка и список.На выходе надо заменить символ в строке на точку таким образом,что цифра в списке должна соответствовать номеру символа в строке, т е в списке нам даны номера символов,которые надо заменить на точку

Comment: @AndrewKonstantinov, добавьте эту информацию в сам вопрос (нажмите "правка" под вопросом и отредактируйте текст).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте просто составить новую строку со своими правилами:

```
text = 'IIIIIIIII'
inds = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

new_text = ''

for i, s in enumerate(text, 1):
    if i in inds:
        new_text += '.'
    else:
        new_text += s

print(new_text) # .....IIII
```

Для любителей писать в одну строку:

```
new_text = ''.join('.' if i in inds else s for i, s in enumerate(text, 1))
print(new_text) # .....IIII
```

Comment: получаются лишние символы почему-то.То есть тут надо просто заменить I на точку

Comment: @AndrewKonstantinov, так '!' были заменены на точку в соответствии с номером символа в inds. Про то, что другие символы не нужно оставлять в задаче не было :) тогда просто убрать `else:new_text += s` и "лишние символы" не будут попадать

Comment: старые символы при этом надо оставить.должно получится .....IIIII

Comment: @AndrewKonstantinov, ну так у меня и получилось. В примере я ведь привел вывод в консоль для print